# Is there a way to reference of an input dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, viewchild

My objective is to create buttons that put certain inputs on focus unsing `.setFocus()`. The problem is that these inputs are dynamically created by the user. The user chooses how many inputs there will be in the page, so there is no way for me to reference the inputs statically.

And apart from the problem of dynamically referencing, there is the `@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` problem, since we can't use them dynamically. That's a problem that needs to be solved too. I tried using `ViewContainerRef` without success.

I have researched a lot and I haven't found anything that could solve my problem. This is my first post on Stack Overflow so, please let me know if I wasn't specific enough or if the code I provided isn't enough.

The codes are below:

home.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

//Providers
import { UserDataProvider, DataList } from '../../providers/user-data/user-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  Inputs:number[];
  rowCount:number;
  homeData: DataList;
  titulo: string;
  unidade: string = 'mL/min';
  inputNumber: string = 'input';

  @ViewChild('input') NBicoInput;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public userData: UserDataProvider,
  ) {

  }

  setFocus(index){
    this.inputNumber = 'input'+index;
    this.NBicoInput.setFocus();
  }
}
```

and the part that matters of the home.html:

```
          <ion-row *ngFor="let y of rowCount|times" text-center align-items-center>
          <ion-col align-self-center col-2>{{y}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col text-center align-self-center col-4><ion-input #input></ion-input></ion-col>
          <ion-col align-self-center col-4></ion-col>
          <ion-col class="empty-col" align-self-center col-2><button id= '{{y}}' (click)="setFocus(y)" ion-button small icon-only>
            <ion-icon name="brush"></ion-icon></button></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

In a nutshell, I want to do as if the `'input'` in the `@ViewChild` was a temporary variable. The reference in the html code is denoted by `#input`.

Comment: The answer for my question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862977/9319353