# Is there a way to focus on a dynamically created form on Angular 4/Ionic3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a page with dynamically created forms like this:
[image]
The blank spaces are inputs and the entire row is a button. **Is there a way to click on the button, i.e. the entire row, and select/focus on the correspondent input?** Keep in mind that the number of inputs is determined by the user and there can be up to 300 rows like these on the page.

#### home.ts

```
export class HomePage {

      public homeForm: FormGroup;
      
      constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public userData: UserDataProvider,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        public renderer: Renderer,
        public elementRef: ElementRef
      ) {

        this.homeForm = new FormGroup({
          bicos: new FormArray([
            new FormControl(null)
          ])
      });

       addInputs() {
          (<FormArray>this.homeForm.controls['bicos'])
          .push(new FormControl(null));
    }
}
```

#### home.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="homeForm"> 
    <ion-row formArrayName="bicos" *ngFor="let item of homeForm.controls.bicos.controls; let i = index" >
        <button id={{i}} ion-button clear style="color: black" class='hidden-button' (click) = "doSomething()">
    <ion-col align-self-center col-2>{{i+1}}</ion-col>
         <ion-col text-center align-self-center col-5>
           <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
         </ion-col>
             <ion-col align-self-center col-5>400</ion-col>
         </button>
    </ion-row>
</form>
```

I have already tried using directives and such without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ViewChildren` to reference the inputs based on index. Add template ref `#inputs` to your input field:

```html
<ion-input #inputs type="text"></ion-input>
```

In your component import `ViewChildren` and `QueryList` and...

```ts
@ViewChildren('inputs') inputs: QueryList<any>;
```

Then on your button click, where you call `doSomething`, in the code you presented, pass the index and set the focus on that field based on index:

```html
<ion-row formArrayName="bicos" *ngFor="let item of homeForm.controls.bicos.controls; let i = index" >
  <button ion-button (click) = "doSomething(i)">
  <!-- ... -->
```

TS:

```ts
doSomething(index) {
  this.inputs.toArray()[index].setFocus();
}
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3gwv6g?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: Thank you very very much!! It worked like a charm! And it way simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ionic 5. Here is my solution using the input element's  id.

**in the .html:**

```
<input id="input_{{ listItem?.id }}"> </input>
```

**in the .ts file:**

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2)
```

**at the point in the .ts file you want to focus the required input:**

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.renderer
    .selectRootElement(`#input_${listItem.id}`)
    .focus();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: But you're making bad. First it's unnecesary "wait 1 second" (you can omit the second parameter, the setTimeout makes a new detection cycle is executed), second use selectRootElement, when you can use ViewChild or ViewChildren is a bad practice

Comment: When you are talking about one element it makes sense, but the question is when you have list of inputs with dynamic id using Ionic 5 ?

Comment: In Angular (sorry about ionic) the "id" is not important. using ViewChildren you has a QueryList. This QueryList allow "listen" changes -when add or remove-: `this.queryList.changes.subscribe(res=>{...})`, or select one element in position x like: `const element=this.queryList.find((_x,i)=>index==i)`